# Is there anyway to get a graphics object within console program?

Tags: c#, gdi+

I am wondering how to create a graphics object from console program rather than windows form? Anyway to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you want to draw on.

You could call `Graphics.FromImage()`.